# Any foreseeable problem in having a mutator for a collection that accepts a new collection?

Tags: java

As per the title, are there any smells surrounding the provision of a setter that accepts a `List` instantiation for assignment to a instance variable?

i.e.

```
public class Test{
    private List<String> strings;

    public Test() {}

    public void setStrings(List<Strings> strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
    }
}
```

What could be a better approach (domain specifics aside)?

Comment: What do you mean by class variable - an instant field or did you forget the keyword static?

Comment: Oh, you didn't mean class variable but instance variable - I've deleted my post again. Now for instance variable, I don't see why a list should be treated any other way than some other object. So I don't smell anything bad ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the caller of your setter can modify the list, because the caller still has a reference. Consider this code:

```
Test test = new Test();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
test.setStrings(list);
list.clear(); // oops! the state of Test has changed without Test knowing!
```

The better approach is to use a *copy* of the list:

```
public void setStrings(List<Strings> strings) {
    this.strings = new ArrayList<String>(strings);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I asked the question.

Comment: would you suggest the copy idiom for all reference types in the case of a mutator?

Comment: Yes. I also recommend publishing (ie getters) of collections by copy

Comment: is this an example of ensuring encapsulation? why don't auto generated getters/setters do this by default?

Comment: Not encapsulation - it's "safe publishing" (don't hand out references to your mutable fields) and "being defensive" (don't trust your callers)). Auto generated getters/setters *could* do it as an option - you could put it on the Eclipse wishlist. The truth is, it "depends" - if you trust your calling code, there's no need to make a copy, but if you're creating an API that others will use, be defensive.

Comment: yes but, if the copy idiom isn't followed, the reference in the native class becomes available to the caller - I would say that this could break encapsulation if the caller was to change the state of the reference.

Answer (score 1):

This fine (I assume you have a getter as well)  The only thing I might do differently is take a copy of the list rather than a direct assignment.

```
public void setStrings(List<Strings> strings) {
    this.strings = new ArraysList<String>(strings);
}
```